# How to get my JS script to run when select option is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS script to add another select option when the first one has been selected however when I load the page and change the Value I get no result from my script I've ran it through JS Bin and there aren't any syntax errors and no warnings and now I am stuck. Is there some method of getting the result I am looking for??

here is the JS script

```
function bevfoo()
{
    var value  = document.getElementById("pre").value;
    var select = document.getElementById("tod");
    var tod    = document.createElement("select");
    var food   = ["one", "two"];
    var drink  = ["two", "one"];

    if(value === "Food")
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < food.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text  = food[i];
            tod.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
    else if(value === "Beverage")
    {
        for(var d = 0; d < drink.length; d++)
        {
            var option2 = document.createElement("option2");
            option2.text = drink[d];
            tod.appendChild(option2);
        }
    }
}
```

and my HTML code that's supposed to call the JS function that's above

```
<DIV ID="classification">
 <P>Food / Beverage:&nbsp;
  <SELECT NAME="class1" ID="pre" ONCHANGE="bevfoo()">
   <OPTION DISABLED>---Select One---</OPTION>
   <OPTION>Food</OPTION><OPTION>Beverage</OPTION>
  </SELECT><P>
 <P ID="tod">Time Of Day:&nbsp;</P>
</DIV>
```

Comment: where do you put your javascript code? In the head- or body-tag?

Comment: @Niddro actually put the code in an external file

Comment: @Mackan Answers for JQuery are fine with me since I am already using jquery on the site anyways

Comment: if you open the console log (F12 in Chrome), do you get an error message when you change?

Comment: @Niddro I don't get  an error of any kind

Comment: Your `<option>` tags really should include values - `<option value="Food">Mmm, fooood</option>`. You're asking for a value in `document.getElementById("pre").value;`. It might get added by the browser, but why trust it :)

Comment: You should write HTML-tags lowercase!

Comment: @julmot how does it change the fuctioning???

Comment: It will not change anything but it's a convention. This was the convention in the last century...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the created select to the `tod` element

```js
function bevfoo() {
  var value = document.getElementById("pre").value;
  var select = document.getElementById("tod");
  var tod = select.querySelector('select');
  //if the select already exists then use it, else create and append to select
  if (!tod) {
    tod = document.createElement("select");
    select.appendChild(tod)
  }
  var food = ["one", "two"];
  var drink = ["two", "one"];
    tod.innerHTML = '';

  if (value === "Food") {
   for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = food[i];
      tod.appendChild(option);
    }
  } else if (value === "Beverage") {
    for (var d = 0; d < drink.length; d++) {
      var option2 = new Option(drink[d])
      tod.appendChild(option2);
    }
  }
}
bevfoo();
```

```html
<DIV ID="classification">
  <P>Food / Beverage:&nbsp;
    <SELECT NAME="class1" ID="pre" ONCHANGE="bevfoo()">
      <OPTION DISABLED>---Select One---</OPTION>
      <OPTION>Food</OPTION>
      <OPTION>Beverage</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
  </P>
  <P ID="tod">Time Of Day:&nbsp;</P>
</DIV>
```

---

Simplified version

```js
var optionsMap = {
  Food: ["one", "two"],
  Beverage: ["two", "one"]
};

function bevfoo() {
    var value = document.getElementById("pre").value;
    var select = document.getElementById("tod");
    var tod = select.querySelector('select');

    //if the select already exists then use it, else create and append to select
    if (!tod) {
      tod = document.createElement("select");
      select.appendChild(tod)
    }

    tod.innerHTML = '';
    var values = optionsMap[value]
    if (values) {
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        tod.appendChild(new Option(values[i]));
      }
    }
  }
  //set the initial value
bevfoo();
```

```html
<DIV ID="classification">
  <P>Food / Beverage:&nbsp;
    <SELECT NAME="class1" ID="pre" ONCHANGE="bevfoo()">
      <OPTION DISABLED>---Select One---</OPTION>
      <OPTION>Food</OPTION>
      <OPTION>Beverage</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
  </P>
  <P ID="tod">Time Of Day:&nbsp;</P>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that you were never attaching your select element in your dom. Just creating that element does not add it to your dom. Added the select element as a child of classification div.

Also, you had used select2 for beverages, which should have been select

Here's the fiddle for the same -

http://jsfiddle.net/mu8o7dqh/1/

```
function bevfoo()
{
    var classification = document.getElementById("classification");
    var value  = document.getElementById("pre").value;
    var select = document.getElementById("tod");
    var tod    = document.createElement("select");
    var food   = ["one", "two"];
    var drink  = ["two", "one"];
    classification.appendChild(tod);

    if(value === "Food")
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < food.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text  = food[i];
            tod.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
    else if(value === "Beverage")
    {
        for(var d = 0; d < drink.length; d++)
        {
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.text = drink[d];
            tod.appendChild(option2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You might wanna explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.